# Why my RecyclerView.Adapter in onBindViewHolder can't see variable from ViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my code holder can't resolve emailText,nicknameText and permissionsText.
[image] 
Why I can't use it and how ti repare it.

```
public class MemberAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private Cursor mCursor;

    public MemberAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor){
        mContext = context;
        mCursor = cursor;
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.member_item,parent,false);
        return new MemberViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(!mCursor.move(position)){
            return;
        }
        String email = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(RegisterContract.MemberEntry.COLUMN_EMAIL));
        String nickname = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(RegisterContract.MemberEntry.COLUMN_NICKNAME));
        String permissions = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(RegisterContract.MemberEntry.COLUMN_PERMISSIONS));

        holder.emailText.setText(email);
        holder.nicknameText.setText(nickname);
        holder.permissionsText.setText(permissions);


    }


    public class MemberViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView emailText;
        public TextView nicknameText;
        public TextView permissionsText;

        public MemberViewHolder( View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            emailText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailTVRV);
            nicknameText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nicknameTVRV);
            permissionsText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.permTVRV);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: because the super type of `MemberViewHolder` - `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` doesn't have these variables.  You need to declare the concrete type in the class : `public class MemberAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MemberViewHolder>` and update the implemented methods arguments and return types - this is better than casting at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

because you need to cast the holder to your holder type class
try this:

```
((MemberViewHolder)holder).emailText.setText(email);
((MemberViewHolder)holder).nicknameText.setText(nickname);
((MemberViewHolder)holder).permissionsText.setText(permissions);
```

better way is to extend with specific holder type

```
MemberAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MemberViewHolder>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what class you are extending in **MemberAdapter** class. But by guessing I think you are extending:

```
public class MemberViewHolder extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>
```

where this **ViewHolder** class is the a built-in class, you should assign your ViewHolder whch called **MemberViewHolder**. It gonna be as following:

```
public class MemberViewHolder extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MemberAdapter. MemberViewHolder>
```

After adding this you will be asked to implement the convenient functions, after that you would be able to access TextViews through holder based in **onBindViewHolder()** function.